# Issues with calling an API taking too much time to get a response

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire, swifty-json

I am calling API in iOS (swift). Everything works perfectly, but it's taking too much time while getting response approximately 40 or 60 seconds. I don't know why this is happening. Let me show you my API calling method:

**Code**

```
func userDetailAPI(){

    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard

    let uid = "u_id"
    let acctkn = "acc_tkn"


    if preferences.object(forKey: uid) == nil {
        //  Doesn't exist
    } else {
        let u_id = preferences.object(forKey: uid) as! String
        print(u_id)
        let acc_tkn = preferences.object(forKey: acctkn) as! String
        print(acc_tkn)

        let userprofile: [String : Any] = ["user_id":u_id,"access_token":acc_tkn]
        print(userprofile)
        Alamofire.request(userDetails, method: .post, parameters: userprofile).responseJSON { response in
                print("RESPONSE : \(response)")
                let result = response.result.value

            if result != nil{
                let data = result as! [String : AnyObject]


                let userdata = data["data"] as! NSDictionary

                let email = userdata["email"]
                let name = userdata["name"]
                let photo = userdata["photo"]
                //let u_type = userdata["user_type"]!
                self.lblUserName.text = name as? String
                self.lblEmailID.text = email as? String

                let proimgurl = NSURL(string: photo as! String)
                self.imgProPic.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOf: proimgurl! as URL)! as Data)

                //  }
        }

    }
}
}
```

Please check and help me - is this the right method for API calling or is there any other, better way?

Comment: Unrelated but do not use `NS` classes in Swift if there are native counterparts (`NSURL`, `NSData`, `NSDictionary`). And JSON values are never `AnyObject` in Swift 3+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey by the way there is also alamofire image pod is available.
https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage

eg: 
do **import AlamofireImage** into your file and call image url like below:

```
Alamofire.request(image_url, method: .get).responseImage(completionHandler: { (response) in
                        self.your_UIImage_variable.image = response.result.value
                    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of this line

```
self.imgProPic.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOf: proimgurl! as URL)! as Data)
```

so you have almofire request plus blocking main thread until image is downloaded , so consider using the asynchronous , automatic cashing  [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

```
self.imgProPic.sd_setImage(with: proimgurl!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

Also in swift avoid using **NS** stuff like here

```
let userdata = data["data"] as! NSDictionary // use [String:Any]
```

and

```
let proimgurl = NSURL(string: photo as! String) // use URL
```

Comment: AlamofireImage could also be a good idea since it's related third party.

Comment: "avoid using NS"?? Then how I am gonna use Core Data objects?! :(

Comment: @J.Doe Avoid `NSStuff` when possible (usually because there is a "Swift equivalent": `NSDictionary` => `Dictionary`, `NSJSONSerialization` => `JSONSerialization`...

Comment: @J.Doe swift is in ongoing enhancements not only coreData also in auto-layout **NSLayoutConstraint** and other stuff , i say use the thing if available

Answer (score 1):

You should download the ImageView's image from Url in another thread. If you do it in the main thread, it'll slow down your app and ultimately run out of memory.

The below-given line is which causes the problem is below

```
self.imgProPic.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOf: proimgurl! as URL)! as Data)
```

I suggest you use the [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) library.

You can do like something below

```
let imageUrl = URL(string: photo as! String)
self.imgProPic.image.sd_setImage(with: imageUrl, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "profile"), options: .refreshCached, completed: nil)
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, try calling the same web service using API clients such as Postman. If it's taking the same amount of time, then you can't do much about it. Ask the web service developer to optimize the performance.